# Routes and controller actions for an inherited class in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, inheritance, controller

I have been writing my code on top of fat_free_crm which is a popular open source rails crm.

You can check it out here: https://github.com/fatfreecrm/fat_free_crm

I've inherited the model "Lead" and created a new inherited class called "SellerLead". Now, although the inherited class "SellerLead" is quite different from "Lead" class at model-level, they're quite similar at the controller levels i.e. whatever controller actions happen with "Lead" also apply to "SellerLead".

Now, when I try to edit/update/create new "SellerLead" object, it's looking for views in the folder "seller_leads/".

How do I make it look into "leads" folder even for a SellerLead object?

Answer (score 3):

You can handle this in routing level. something like this:

```
resource :seller_leads, :controller => "leads"
```

Hope it is helpful for you.

Comment: It's using the controller actions of "leads" but it's not using the partials of "leads". Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly render a custom view like so:

```
render "leads/show"
```

See section 2.2.3 of [this Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) for more detail.